# Check if category name already exists

Tags: php

I want to add category to my tbl_category. Before add i want to check if category name already exists. I try the following code, but it gives me

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'**

with message

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

```
public function save_category($data) {
        $category_name = $data['category_name'];
        $category_description = $data['category_description'];
        $publication_status = $data['publication_status'];
        $sql =  "SELECT category_name FROM tbl_category WHERE category_name='$category_name' ";
        $result =  $this->pdo->query($sql);
        $num_rows= $result->fetchColumn();
        if($num_rows != 0) {
            echo 'Category already exist';
        }
        else {
            try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category(category_name, category_description, publication_status) VALUES(:category_name, :category_description, :publication_status)";
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':category_name', $category_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':category_description', $category_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':publication_status', $publication_status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $message = "Save category information successfully";
            return $message;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Value of `$category_name` is?

Comment: And btw - why there's a closing bracket in the end of a query?

Comment: @ u_mulder $category_name=$data['category_name']. Closing bracket is a mistake. I remove it. Now i can insert a category multiple times. How can i prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nishan, use $this->pdo->prepare in select too.
And change "fetchColumn()" for "rowCount()" see correct code

```
public function save_category($data) {
    $category_name = $data['category_name'];
    $category_description = $data['category_description'];
    $publication_status = $data['publication_status'];
    $result = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT category_name FROM tbl_category WHERE category_name='$category_name'");
    if($result->execute()){
    $num_rows= $result->rowCount();
    if($num_rows != 0) {
        echo 'Category already exist';
    }
    else {
        try {
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_category(category_name, category_description, publication_status) VALUES(:category_name, :category_description, :publication_status)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':category_name', $category_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':category_description', $category_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':publication_status', $publication_status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $message = "Save category information successfully";
        return $message;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        } 
    }
    } else {
        echo "error in select";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Also PDOStatement::columnCount working too.

Answer (score 0):

Which query is the error for, the select or insert?

Try the [debugDumpParams function](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php%20debugDumpParams) and see if it gives you any clues:

```
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```